# Why is constructor function not setting <h6> text correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am using OOP principles to create a bunch of graphs. Everything works fine except the setting of text values. I need to set the title of each graph but instead I am getting blank values.

My code: The controller file, i.e. `main.js` does all the data manipulation and creates new graphs by invoking the constructor function (stored in `mainSlopeGraph.js`) with arguments that include the `id` of `<h6>` element and text to fill it with.

Relevant code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 descGraph">
        <h6 id="provinceNameBaloch"></h6>
        <h6 id="provinceNameICT"></h6>
        <h6 id="provinceNamePunjab"></h6>
        <h6 id="provinceNameSindh"></h6>
        <h6 id="provinceNameKPK"></h6>
        <p>Add some words talking about the trend.</p>
      </div>
```

main.js:

```
slopeGraphKPK = new SlopeGraph(
    "#chart1",
    updatedKPKData,
    dataKPKDomain,
    "#provNameKPK",
    provNameKPK
  );
  slopeGraphPunjab = new SlopeGraph(
    "#chart2",
    updatedPunjabData,
    dataPunjabDomain,
    "#provNamePunjab",
    provNamePunjab
  );
  slopeGraphICT = new SlopeGraph(
    "#chart3",
    updatedICTData,
    dataICTDomain,
    "#provNameICT",
    provNameICT
  );
  slopeGraphSindh = new SlopeGraph(
    "#chart4",
    updatedSindhData,
    dataSindhDomain,
    "#provNameSindh",
    provNameSindh
  );
  slopeGraphBaloch = new SlopeGraph(
    "#chart5",
    updatedBalochData,
    dataBalochDomain,
    "#provNameBaloch",
    provNameBaloch
  );
```

mainSlopeGraph.js:

```
  SlopeGraph = function(
  _parentElement,
  _someData,
  _someDomain,
  _provNamePlaceholder,
  _provName
) {
  this.parentElement = _parentElement;
  this.provData = _someData;
  this.scaleDomain = _someDomain;
  this.provNamePlaceholder = _provNamePlaceholder;
  this.provName = _provName;
  this.initVis();
};

SlopeGraph.prototype.initVis = function() {
  let vis = this;

  console.log(vis.provNamePlaceholder);
  console.log(vis.provName);


  $(vis.provNamePlaceholder).text(vis.provName);
  // $("#provinceName").textContent = vis.provName;
  // $("#provinceName").innerText = vis.provName;
  // $("#provinceName").innerHTML = vis.provName;
.
.
.
}
```

In case, here is all the code: https://github.com/SabahatPK/Data4Pakistan_SlopeGraphs
And this is output: https://data-driven-pakistan-data-stories.netlify.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML you use `provinceNameKPK` and alike, in your js however you use `provNameKPK`.
So

```
slopeGraphKPK = new SlopeGraph(
    "#chart1",
    updatedKPKData,
    dataKPKDomain,
    "#provNameKPK",
    provNameKPK
  );
```

must be

```
slopeGraphKPK = new SlopeGraph(
    "#chart1",
    updatedKPKData,
    dataKPKDomain,
    "#provinceNameKPK", // prov => province
    provNameKPK
  );
```

and so on